# Java self signed certificate imported to trusted list before hand will still show security warning the first time

Tags: java, java-web-start, client-certificates

I have a problem with the obscure subject of self-signed certificates. I have created a keystore using keytool and then created a self-signed certificate.  Currently what happens is that the first time the java application is downloaded using Java Web Start a security prompt is shown and after accepting it the certificate is saved in the Java Control Panel trusted list as expected. Obviously the application jar files within the war have been signed using the same keystore.

However, I would have thought that if I manually import the certificate to the Java Control Panel trusted list before hand, then the security prompt should not show, not even the first time. However the security prompt will always pops up the first time even that I have manually imported certificate to the trusted list before hand.

Is this happening by design? meaning that, always the user will be forced to select "don't show this warning again option" at least once? or is it possible that I am missing something? The security level in Java control panel is as low as possible. Also the Java Web Start URL has been added to the Exception Site list. The security prompt looks like below image.

[Security Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdiAg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way of avoiding security warning to pop up even the first time. I have tested in Windows 10 and Java 7 and Java 8, therefore in later versions of Java or in other operating systems there may be different results. Also it's worth noting that this is not recommended in terms of security risk unless your intranet or production environment's security is assured.

[image: Security Warning]

The above security warning will always pop up unless the following steps are followed:

1. Create your self signed certificate using keytool, and sing all your jars within your Java Web Start bundle with the same keystore used to create YourCertificate.crt
2. Open your Java Control Panel and delete cache by click on Settings and then click on Delete Files and select Delete Applications option and OK
   [image: Delete Cache]
3. To import Your Certificate before running the app, go to Security tab and click on Manage Certificates and then click Import and select YourCertificate.crt and click Open
   (It's also recommended to add your domain to Exception Site List)

   [image: Import Certificate to Java Control Panel]
4. Now your self signed certificate is a Trusted Certificate
   [image: Import Certificate to Java Control Panel]
5. Go to Advanced tab and select Disable Verification in the Mixed Code (Sandboxed vs Trusted) security verification<
   [image: Import Certificate to Java Control Panel]
6. Run your Java Web Start app that was signed with the same keystore and security warning will not ever show.

Comment: Forgot to add the article that I used as reference for this answer, which is below: https://windowsreport.com/disable-java-security-warning-pop-windows-8/